# In SmartTarget, what's the difference between facet promotion and item promotion in your template?

Tags: smarttarget

What's the difference between a facet promotion and an item promotion?

Answer (score 4):

Facet promotions are based on the visitor's location on the website (structure group = static, keyword from navigation = dynamic). Item promotions show content related to another Component Presentation, such as the main article on the page.

Answer (score 4):

When you publish content to smarttarget meta information such as name, keywords, structure group, folder etc are also published by default (this is also completely extendable).

You can then build faceted navigation based on this information.  This is termed 'faceted promotion'

Item promotions are based on relationships between different component presentations, rather than configured facets.

Best way to learn the differences is to consult the online documentation and have a play with the preview area of the smarttarget manager.

Comment: Good answer, although the intention behind Item promotions really is to show content related to another Component Presentation (as I mentioned in the webinar where this Q/A is from). In the future we will likely remove this arbitrary distinction between the different types of queries, since the products have evolved quite a bit since their introduction.