# Item Promotion in SmartTarget 2014

Tags: smarttarget

Possibly related to this question:
[In SmartTarget, what's the difference between facet promotion and item promotion in your template?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3633/46) -- in SmartTarget 2014, the Item tag (`<tcdl:item>`) and **SmartTarget Items TBB** seem to be related to *search* rather than a given Component Presentation on a page.

How would you promote items related to a Component Presentation presented on a given page (i.e. automatically add "related links" for a given article)?

The [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1/GUID-858499D1-DE15-4B4B-9450-17ED9E7BEC96) explains:

> the Show SmartTarget Items Template Building Block inserts code in
>   your Web pages to insert content items. It is used to handle content
>   items related to the search query, amongst others.

I'm interested in the "amongst others" part. :-)

**Edit**: made main question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot create Item Promotions in SmartTarget 2014. Although you can create your own trigger (so the Promotion would show up), you cannot have that Promotion return items that are related to the Component Presentation.

It was always unclear to me exactly what Fredhopper considered "related" anyway, so it seemed like a good way to make sure you had *no idea* what was being displayed for your Promotion :)

No big loss to me, then, but I understand that it would be an issue if you used these in the past. If enough people want these types of Promotions, perhaps it can be introduced in a future version of SmartTarget.

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking the CD API can still handle this use case then. Otherwise after creating our own trigger, `Select Content by Keyword` may be enough to show what we'd want, even if not based on a specific CP on the page.

Comment: Indeed, that's probably the direction to take. You can also do some pretty fancy things with trigger-based filtering.